# Google chrome opens new tab on each link, mousewheel is zoom?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Somehow every once in a while google chrome will get to a setting where it opens each link I click into a new tab, along with that it also will zoom when scrolling the mouse wheel.

What setting is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is caused by the `CTRL` key being stuck with *Windows Sticky Keys*.  It is annoying, and I would disable it completely, but have found no way that works permanently regardless of what I check in the Accessibility Control Panel.

A quick fix that will temporarily restore normal functionality is to press and hold both `CTRL` keys for about 3 seconds.  If that doesn't work, open the `Windows Onscreen Keyboard` located at *`%windir%\System32\osk.exe`*.

When you open it, you can see a visual illustration of the keys both being pressed.  Sometimes this is caused by a hardware problem - e.g. spilled juice on keyboard, but sometimes I find that it just likes to mess with you, and you can manually 'unpress' them using the OSK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course I have also seen the CTRL key get stuck because the computer user gets crumbs, and other crap stuck in their keyboard.  If the keyboard hasn't been cleaned in a while it is probably time to clean it.

Comment: Mine happens from a combination of VM's and the Java Robot class (seems it presses both CTRLs when you ask it to press CTRL).

Comment: @BumSkeeter that may be a great tip.  I'll keep my eyes out for that next time it happens.